# Finding the tinyest variable in a program?

Tags: c++

I am having a hard time understanding how to keep track of a an int in a function. The program reads user input, for example "10, 9, 8, 7, 1, 20". It should assign 10 as the "smallest" number. The first number the user inputs is always the smallest temporary value. and then if user enters another number, say 9, it compares 9 < 10, and updates the smallest number. The problem I am having is that my smallest number inside a function is just the next number the user inputs, so if the user input 20, smallest number would be 20.

In other words, a program that saves the first user input, and keeps reading user input and only updates when it is smaller than the first user input. Can't use arrays to save user input.

```
int smallest;
int someFunction(int r){
smallest = r;


int tempvalue = r;
    
if (tempvalue < smallest){
   smallest = r;
  }
}
```

Comment: It won't work, becasue, each time your are passing a value to a function, it treats it as a new value, and both the variables store the new value as smallest as well as temporary. Try to pass the values as an array of numbers, or try to run a loop inside main(), without passing it to any function.

Comment: The smallest variable isn't saved inside the function. But the instructions are to make the first input the smallest variable. And then compare for every other input that comes in.

Comment: Your `int someFunction(int r)` must return a value other than that your problem is `smallest` is initialized to 0 at the start of the program (before `int main()`) because its a global variable. You may want to initialize it to the `std::numeric_limits<int>::max();` related: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
#include <stdint.h> // INT_MAX

// As its name implies INT_MAX is the largest value for an int.

int main()
{
   int user_input;
   int min_value = INT_MAX;  // store your min value in a durable and
                             // accessible scope... It could  also be 
                             // a global variable, which would make it
                             // accessible from another function.

   while (/* .... */ )       // plug in your favorite logic for an input loop                  
   {
       // add code to read user input, store in variable user_input

       // on the first run, whatever the user inputs has to be
       // less or equal to MAX_INT.   

       if (user_input < min_value)   // check against stored value.
          min_value = user_input; 
   } 
}
```